# Info or Not secure on ssl problem only one page

Tags: ssl

i have a purchase SSL to install my website only index.php page is not secure and all website page are secure. understand through the screen short[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoZgN.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtcNT.png)

Answer (score 1):

In your contact us `form` section there is `action attribute` with value is

```
action="http://demo.themefisher.com/themefisher/bingo/sendmail.php"
```

Change it to(`https`)

```
action="https://demo.themefisher.com/themefisher/bingo/sendmail.php"
```

Just include all urls with `https` to secure the page.